# Using a Login component outside of my router/routes and navbar

Tags: reactjs, navigation, react-hooks, react-router-dom

Trying to learn react and I created a Navbar with a simple list of links that point to routes in App.tsx. As it's working currently, all my components display the Navbar. Including the Login component, which is not what I want.

The behavior I'm looking for would display the login component without the Navbar when the app is launched, so path "/". And then once they click the login button, it would "log them in" and display a default component with the Navbar and allow them to move around the app.

Before I get into the state part, I need to know how I can go about achieving this first. I tried re-arranging the Navbar position in App.tsx to no avail (the Navbar contains links, so it has to be within a Router). All the other routes need the navbar as well, so it makes sense to put it first, except for login (or any other page I don't want to include the navbar).

I'll leave out my Navbar component since it just has links. But my App component looks like this, which hopefully is enough to explain what I'm missing:

```
App.tsx:

 import * as React from "react";
 import { useState } from "react";
 import "./index.css";
 import {
   BrowserRouter as Router,
   Switch,
   Route,
   Redirect,
} from "react-router-dom";
 import Navbar from "./components/Navbar";
 import VisitLog from "./components/VisitList";
 import Dashboard from "./components/Dashboard";
 import Profile from "./components/Profile";
 import Login from "./components/Login"

 export default function App() {
    const [loggedIn, setLoggedIn] = useState(false);

    return (
      <div>
       <Router>
        <Navbar />
         <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/" />
          <Route path="/profile" component={Profile} />
          <Route path="/visits" component={VisitLog} />
          <Route path="/dashboard" component={Dashboard} />
          <Route path="/login" component={Login} />
        </Switch>
      </Router>
   </div>
 );
}
```

Do I need to rework my navbar and routes completely or is there a relatively simple way to make exceptions to which components see the navbar?

Also, I'm open to other ideas to achieve a similar effect. It's just a standard practice in any website to display login page if not logged in, but I wasn't able to find much for my navbar display purposes.

Pretty simple. I must be missing something.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What if you avoid render navbar if user is not logged in and redirect it to '/login'path.

```
    return (
      <div>
       <Router>
        {lodggedIn ? <Navbar /> : <Redirect to="/login"/>}
         <Switch>
            <Route path='/login' component={() => <Login setLogin={(islogged)=> setIslogged(isLogged)}/>}/>            
         </Switch>
      </Router>
   </div>
 );
```

And in your Login component you pass the result of the login attempt to the setLogin function in props.
example:

```
function attemptLogin(){
   let result = get login results
   this.props.setLogin(result);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, works great. I think I tried this but I must have put it in the wrong place. But how do I get my login component to tell my App component that the logged in prop is true? How to call App.setLoggedIn(true) ? Thanks !

Comment: Check the update. Otherwise you can place all the router into the loggedIn true statement. EX: {loggedIn ? <Router .../> : <Login setLogin={(islogged)=> this.setState({islogged})}/>.